# Angular JS href generated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

using angularjs (+ionic) I'm trying to do this:

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-repeat="button in MenuButtons" {{button.type}}={{button.link}}>
```

the result I would expect is:

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-repeat="button in MenuButtons" href="mypage.html">
```

instead I get:

```
<ion-item menu-close="" ng-repeat="button in MenuButtons" {{button.type}}="{{button.link}}" class="item ng-binding" style="">
```

My problem is with {{button.type}}={{button.link}}

That said the following is working for me just fine where the link is "mypage.html":

```
href={{button.link}} --> href="mypage.html"
```

what am I missing?

Comment: angular doesn't create attributes , it only interprets existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind attribute name through `{{}}` Angular expression.
Instead try this with `ng-href`:

```
<ion-item ng-href="{{pageName}}.html"></ion-item>
```

More details at this [Angular ng-href article](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try to write init function and do this javascriptly. (Please check to getElementById and setAttribute. There must be another way.)

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-repeat="button in MenuButtons" id="{{button.id}}" ng-init="createHref(button)">

$scope.createHref= function(btn){
    document.getElementById(btn.id).setAttribute(btn.type,btn.link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the feedback!
based on your answer I decided to use ng-if since I may or may not have a href.
so my code looks like this now

```
        <span ng-repeat="button in MenuButtons">
        <span ng-if="button.type === 'href'">
            <ion-item menu-close href={{button.link}}>
                <i class={{button.class}}></i> {{button.name}}
        </span>
```